QGIS processing plugin: How to select the current layer?
I want to create a plugin, where you create a copy of the selected layer from the project but where you rename the variables in it.
I created processing plugin as described here https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_python_plugin.html. The description, how to start is very good, however, then, when it comes to understand the automatically generated code, it stops to be that clear. I would at first like to be able to print the name of the layer selected within the plugin gui.
In the GUI the processing PlugIn looks like this: 
In the automatically created python-file pluginName_algorithm.py there is a class with the PluginNameAlgorithm and then Input and Output. I guess it must be here? And if so, how can I communicate with the gui from here?
This is the class:
PluginNameAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    Input = 'Input'
    Output = 'Output'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config):
                """
        Here we define the inputs and output of the algorithm, along
        with some other properties.
        """

        # We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )

        # We add a feature sink in which to store our processed features (this
        # usually takes the form of a newly created vector layer when the
        # algorithm is run in QGIS).
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )
         



If you use the 'Processing Provider' template of the Plugin-Builder, the UI-elements are created based on the addParameter-Method in your instance of QgsProcessingAlgorithm, and are not easily accessible. The user inputs to these auto-generated UI-elements (Input-Layer, Output-Layer in your example) are however accesible trough the 'parameters'-Dictionary, which is passed to the processAlgorithm-Method in your PluginNameAlgorithm-Class.
To simply print the Input Layer you could modify the processAlgorithm-Method like this:
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
       input_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(parameters['INPUT'])
       print(input_lyr)
       ### do stuff
       return ...

If you, however, want to create a more complex UI, (add custom Widgets, connect signals, etc) i would suggest to use one of the other templates in the Plugin Builder, where you can directly access the UI-elements in the class contained in '_dialog.py'.

Thank you @juliustoth! I have created another plugin with another template, however that one needed direct interaction with the layer (selecting objects and change values in their attributes). However,  adding new fields with specific names shouldn't be too complex...or I hope so :)
